# Unhealthy instances for load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, subnet, private-subnet, loadbalancer

I have two ec2 instances on private subnets, both instances have the same efs mounted on which there is a flask application called microblog.
In logged into both and have run flask run --host=0.0.0.0.0 so both have microblog running.

Instance 1:

- Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0.0).
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
- Running on http://10.0.0.186:5000

Instance 2:

- Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0.0)
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
- Running on http://10.0.1.149:5000

The goal is to have a load balancer distribute the incoming traffic between the two instances, for this I created an application load balancer by selecting the same VPC but this time on the public subnets. The internet ingress to the load balancer occurs on port 80, so I have created a listening agent on port 80.
For the target group I have chosen port 5000 which is where the application is running, the same VPC as the load balancer and the instances.
But the instances always appear as unhealthy.

To check that the instances were responding on port 5000

I did a `curl -I http://localhost:5000/` and it responded with :

```
TTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Server: Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.9.16
Date: Fri, 23 Feb 2024 18:23:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 227
Location: /auth/login?next=%2F
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: session=eyJfZmxhc2hlcyI6W3siIHQiOlsibWVzc2FnZSIseyIgbSI6IlBsZWFzZSBsb2cgaW4gdG8gYWNjZXNzIHRoaXMgcGFnZS4ifV19XX0.Zdjikg.rqq8t9GqtM_sWsnJ6ReqDezT7y4; HttpOnly; Path=/
Connection: close
```

Seeing that I was doing the redirection, I did the curl again but this time to

`curl -I http://localhost:5000/auth/login?next=%2F`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Werkzeug/2.2.2 Python/3.9.16
Date: Fri, 23 Feb 2024 18:24:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 7012
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: session=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiMGJmNWU3ZjIzNDAzM2Y5ZTM4M2QwMjI2NTJiMDExZZWFjNTA3MDA3NyJ9.Zdji0g.e7x7CseuQYu_yfO0-0Yuzulz
LcM; HttpOnly; Path=/
Connection: close
```

And as I was getting 200 as response I edited the Status check path and put "/auth/login?next=%2F"

But the instances are still returning unhealthy with the reason "Request timed out".

The security group of the load balancer allows entries on port 5000 and port 80
And the instances share the same security group that also allows port 5000 and port 80 coming from the load balancer.

Comment: From where did you run the `curl` commands? (Presumably from an EC2 instance in the public subnet?) Are you using a **Network Load Balancer** or an **Application Load Balancer**? Generally, it is better to **use a different Security Group** on your Load Balancer and your EC2 instances since they each have different roles in your architecture. Can you show us the configuration of your Security Group?

Comment: Its ALB. I have tried curl in both directions to port 5000 of the other instance. And in both cases I get a response. I have also tried to curl from the bastion host I have in the public subnet and I also get a response.
Both ec2 of the private subnet have the same security group: Port 80 (from the loadbalancer) Port 22 (from the bastion host) Port 5000(0.0.0.0.0/0, I know it should not be done but as I am testing and it does not work, right now I have it like this) and Port 3306 for the database.
The sg of the balancer has port 80 (0.0.0.0.0/0) and port 5000(0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: Does the security group on the Load Balancer permit **outbound** connections to port 5000 to the EC2 instances?

Comment: You say "the instances share the same security group", so are you using the same security group for both the Load Balancer and the EC2 instances? If so, that could be the problem because you say they "allows port 5000 and port 80 coming from the load balancer" but that is not a good rule for incoming traffic to the Load Balancer (which should accept traffic from `0.0.0.0/0`). Please show us the exact configuration of the security groups, or create separate security groups for the Load Balancer and the EC2 instances.

Comment: Currently my configuration is
ALB - inbound rules, port 80 and port 5000, source 0.0.0.0.0/0
EC2 (one in one az and one in another az, but both in privateS subnet) with inbound rules: - Port 80 (from loadbalancer) - Port 22 (from bastion host) - Port 5000(0.0.0.0.0/0, I know it should not be done but as I am testing and it is not working, right now I have it like this) - Port 3306 for database and Port 2049 for EFS.

Comment: The application that is running on both ec2 is in an EFS, can this be related to the problem?

Comment: No. The health check calls the URL that you provide. If it responds with a `200` then it is marked as `Healthy`.

Comment: The application is not responding 200 on the "/", if you see my first post, on the "/" it does a 302 to "Location: /auth/login?next=%2F" so I have set it to do the health check on "/auth/login?next=%2F" but it still shows unhealthy "Request timed out". If I do a curl from ec2 to :5000/auth/login?next=%2F I get code 200.

Comment: One option is to add another page to your app specifically for the Health Check that does not do a redirect.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That is what is done right now. 
When I do `curl -I http://localhost:5000/auth/login?next=%2F` I get response 200, so I have set the health check to do it on `/auth/login?next=%2F,` but it still gives the same error and the instances are unhealthy.